# The cat in the hat

Tags: cipher, steganography

> “When begtles fight thase battles in v bottle with  their paddles 
>   and the bottle's on a piodle and the poodly's eating  noodles...
>   ...they call this a muddls puddle tweotle poodle bgetle nogdle 
>   bottle poddle battle.”
>
> I am a:

**hint #1**

> Would you like a little clue? 
>  Sally said "I do. I do".
>  I am the author of this tale
>  if you know my name you might prevail.

Comment: Another hint? Possibly?

Comment: Hint? @Buildstarted?

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

This text is originally

> a passage from Dr. Seuss's ["Fox in Socks"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_in_Socks). The original passage reads:
>
>  "When beetles fight these battles in a bottle with their paddles
>  and the bottle's on a poodle and the poodle's eating noodles...
>  ...they call this a muddle puddle tweetle poodle beetle noodle
>  bottle paddle battle."

Highlighting the differences:

> "When be**g**tles fight th**a**se battles in **v** bottle with their paddles
>  and the bottle's on a p**i**odle and the poodl**y**'s eating noodles...
>  ...they call this a muddl**s** puddle twe**o**tle poodle b**g**etle no**g**dle
>  bottle p**o**ddle battle."
>
>  The changed letters spell **gaviysoggo**.

Perhaps someone more experienced with this type of puzzle will be able to take it from here...

Comment: Side note: I recognized the text immediately because this was my favorite book as a little kid. I would ask my mom to read it so often that she started flat-out refusing because she was so tired of all the tongue-twisters :-)

Comment: One of my favorite scenes from 3rd Rock. :) You're on your way to solving it.

Comment: @Buildstarted Ah, I haven't seen any 3rd Rock—is there a reference involved that I would need to be aware of to solve the puzzle?

Comment: Not at all. No hint in these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @ETHProductions' partial answer of

> I will add the changed letters, so we have:
>
> ```
> gaviysoggo
> eeaoeeeeou
> ```
>
> All vowels. I find that interesting. Probably not the number of letters between the changed letters, then.

Comment: Heh, I actually had this too, but I didn't think it would be important so I didn't include it in my partial answer. But who knows...